# Auto scale text (font size) according to EditText view Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

I want to resize the (font size) text according to the size of EditText (whose size is fixed). Android.

Comment: What that mean exactly?

Comment: @Khemraj to be exact - Reducing the font size as string length increases, in a way that it fits the entire EditText.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this library which is a TextView that automatically resizes text to fit perfectly within its bounds.

https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview

and also google IntroducedAutoSizeTextView in api26 for more information see the documentation : 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview